# Отправка формы при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript, sendmail, google-spreadsheet

Добрый день, хочу поинтересоваться, кто-то делал отправку писем через гугл таблицы? Т.е, проворачивал ли, кто-то вот такую схему "сайт -> гугл таблица -> почта" при помощи js? Или же, можете ли вы, подсказать иной способ отправки форм с сайта, с использованием js?

Comment: если вы посчитали ответ правильным, пожалуйста не забывайте отметить его как верный. Это можно сделать, нажав галочку слева от него, под рейтингом комментария.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Или же, можете ли вы, подсказать иной способ отправки форм с сайта, с
>   использованием js?

Да, такие варианты есть, например - использовать [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/). Другой вариант - [использовать JS GMail API](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-gmail-javascript-api/). Остальные варианты без труда ищутся по запросу `send emails javascript`.

> Добрый день, хочу поинтересоваться, кто-то делал отправку писем через
>   гугл таблицы? Т.е, проворачивал ли, кто-то вот такую схему "сайт ->
>   гугл таблица -> почта" при помощи js?

Именно такая схема не имеет смысла, есть смысл просто параллельно организовать в коде отправку и письма, и лида в GD. Для работы с последним вы также можете найти множество примеров реализации в сети, включая [документацию от самого Google](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).